# search of string in an array of strings

Tags: c, pointers

i wrote some code that is supposed to find the location of a given string in an array of strings.
problem is- it doesn't give the location. it gives something else.

i understand that probably the problem has to do with the differences between the pointers that are involved- a previous version that dealt with finding the position of a letter in a word worked well.
after a lot of attempts to figure out where is the bug, i ask your help.
kindly, explain me what should be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int what (char * token);

main()
{
    int i=0;
    char  string[]="jsr";
    char *token;
    token=&string[0];
    i=what(token);
    printf(" location of input is %d \n", i);
    return 0;

}   

int what (char * token)
{
    int i=1;
    char *typtbl[]={"mov",
        "cmp",
        "add",
        "sub",
        "not",
        "clr",
        "lea",

    };  

    char * ptr;

    ptr=(char *)typtbl;
    while (!(strcmp(ptr,token)==0))
    {
        ptr=(char *)(typtbl+i);
        i++;
    }   
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Please, review your code indentation.

Comment: it was written nice ... having a trouble with putting it into the post without losing the indentation

Comment: 1) why use `(char *)(typtbl+i)` instead of clear `typtbl[i]`? 2) what should happen if `what` doesn't find requiered string? 3) how the while-loop determines that there is nothing left in `typtbl`?

Comment: that works! thank you! can you explain the difference?

Comment: @davidku if you ask question here, just make sure the indentation is not completely messed up. That's _your_ job.

Comment: I fix the indent, impossible to read without correct indent

Comment: These are is wrong regardless: `(char *)typtbl;` and `ptr=(char *)(typtbl+i);` Make not while learning the language: anytime a hard cast is required to squelch warnings or errors, it is *highly* likely you're doing something that is *highly* likely wrong. `char**` is not equivalent to `char*`, casting it doesn't make it magically better.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you did not design function `what` properly. What value should it return if your search function go through all the pointers but does not find the desired string? Typically in that case return `-1` would be a choice to indicate nothing found. Also in this case, using a `for` loop would probably be more suitable, you can just return the index immediately instead of going through all pointers.

```
int what(char *token)
{
    char *typtbl[] = {
        "mov",
        "cmp",
        "add",
        "sub",
        "not",
        "clr",
        "lea",

    };

    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(typtbl)/sizeof(char*); ++i )
    {
        char *ptr = typtbl[i];
        if(strcmp(ptr, token) == 0)
        {
            return i;  // found something
        } 
    }

    return -1;  // found nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner working version.

Main issue is in the `(char *)(typtbl+i)` replaced by `typtbl[i]` in the following code.     `typtbl+i` is equivalent to `&typtbl[i]`, so if my memory is good, it's a pointer on the pointer of the string and not the pointer of string itself

I added a NULL at the end of the array to be able to stop if the string is not present and return -1 to clearly say it was not found.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int what(char *token);

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char string[] = "jsr";
    i = what(string);
    printf(" location of input is %d \n", i);
    return 0;
}

int what(char *token)
{
    char *typtbl[] = {
        "mov",
        "cmp",
        "add",
        "jsr",
        "not",
        "clr",
        "lea",
        NULL
    };

    int i = 0;
    while(typtbl[i] && !(strcmp(typtbl[i], token) == 0)) {
        ++i;
    }

    if(!typtbl[i])
        i = -1;

    return i;
}
```

`char *token; token=&string[0];` was useless because `string == &string[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Your main function is missing its return type.
- The while loop in *what* doesn't stop when the element isn't found. Therefore you are reading out of bounds.

This should do the work w/o pointer arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int what (char * token);

int main(){
    int i=0;
    char  string[]="jsr";
    char *token;
    token=&string[0];
    i=what(token);
    printf(" location of input is %d \n", i);
    return 0;
}   

int what (char * token){
    unsigned int i=0;
    char *typtbl[]={"mov",
        "cmp",
        "add",
        "sub",
        "not",
        "clr",
        "lea",

    };  
    unsigned int typtbl_x_size = sizeof(typtbl)/sizeof(typtbl[0]);
    char * ptr;

    ptr=typtbl[i];
    while (!(strcmp(ptr,token)==0)){
        i += 1;
        if (i >= typtbl_x_size){
            printf("element not in list\n");
            return -1;
        }
        ptr=typtbl[i];
    }   
    return i;
}
```

Comment: one could add some smaller improvements but this should do it job. :)